# Reg-Free COM written in 1C language

Tags: dcom, regfreecom

I'm writting application in C which calls functions from a DCOM object.
The DCOM is stored in DLL written in 1C language.

My application is working fine when DCOM is registred in a system.
Is there is a way to call functions from the *.dll using Reg-Free (I mean: without registration the .dll in a system)?

I've tried many times to do so but I've failed. 
I used `mt` (from Visual Studio) to embed a manifest xml to the dll but it doesn't work .

The .dll manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="DrvFR" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<file name="DrvFR.dll">
    <comClass clsid="{E187099F-8C5C-4723-8866-D8DBB6353ADE}" threadingModel="Apartment"/>
</file>
</assembly>
```

My application manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="AutomaticCommPortDetector" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="DrvFR" version="1.0.0.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

Comment: The manifest in the DLL can only be activated when the DLL gets loaded.  Which produces the common chicken-and-egg problem, the OS can't find the DLL (or the comClass) so can't load it.  Put the egg before chicken and move those manifest entries in the app manifest.

Comment: I'm note sure what are you mean. I put the file node (from the .dll manifest) to the app manifest but it doesn't work, the app can't even run (previously it run but creating a COM object fails).

Comment: The only thing that "it doesn't work" ever tells me is that you are doing it wrong.  The OS won't start the program when it cannot parse the manifest.  It will leave an event in the Windows Application event log that contains the details, showing the exact line and column number of the bad manifest entry.

Comment: Unfortunately application starts when I use the manifests mentioned before (but the app can't create the com objects with required functions).

Comment: SxS Activation does not support out of process servers (DCOM).  Are you sure you are using that here?